# require() breaking in React Native after upgrading Node to v8.9.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, I'm attempting to `require` some static PNGs for thumbnails. Per the React Native docs, I load them using `require` i.e.:

```
<View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressHandler()}>
      <Image style={styles.thumbnail} source={require('./toner.png')} />
   </TouchableOpacity>
   <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
</View>
```

This works fine on my home machine where I use Node v7.6.0. However, it error gets thrown on my work machine using Node v8.9.0. The error:

> Unable to resolve module './toner.png'.

It complains that the module does not exist, but it does! I'm guessing this is something breaking with Node v8.9.0 but I'm not positive. Any thoughts on how to remedy would be appreciated!